# See value of a JavaScript variable in another html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

There are two files: 1)app.js and 2) browser.html. app.js just stores a value  in a node-js local storage and browser.html should alerts that. But browser.html alerts "null".
My JavaScript code:

```
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
var a="salam";
    global.a=a;
    localStorage.setItem('a',a);
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<title>TEST</title>
   </head>
<body>
<input value="Smart contract data" max="25" id="12"></input>
    <script src='js/app.js'>  </script>
    <script>
    alert(localStorage.getItem('a'));
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem and its solution? Is there any way to communicate between node-js storage and a html file? Please guide a beginner man.

Comment: Do u want to run a node js server and the user should see the html page when he visits the site?

Comment: Yes, that is true

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that node-localstorage is entirely backend, and htlm5 localStorage is entirely client side. You will not be able to pull backend values set with node-localstorage on the client end.

In order to pass values from node to the client you will need a template engine. Express provides a pretty complete list of those engines here:
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

Comment: Thanks. Is it any different to choose one of these engines?